# Find the asymptotic distribution of $T_n = \frac{X (n-Y)}{Y(n-X)}$ where X and Y are binomial distributed

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables distributed, respectively, as Binomial$(n, \pi_1)$ and Binomial$(n, \pi_2)$. Find the asymptotic distribution of $T_n = \frac{X (n-Y)}{Y(n-X)}$ as $n \to \infty$.

How to solve out the above question? My idea is for large $n$, binomial distributions are approximately normal. But I don't think this is a correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ (resp. $Y$) can be seen as a sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli variables $\mathcal{B}(\pi_1)$ (resp.  $\mathcal{B}(\pi_2)$), then, by central limit theorem and as $X,Y$ are independent, we have:
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\pmatrix{X/n \\Y/n} -\pmatrix{\pi_1 \\\pi_2}  \right)\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N}_2 \left(\pmatrix{0 \\0} ,\underbrace{\pmatrix{\pi_1(1-\pi_1)&0 \\0&\pi_2(1-\pi_2)}}_{:=\Sigma}  \right)$$

We observe that the random variable $T_n$ can be written as
$$T_n =\frac{X/n (1-Y/n)}{Y/n (1-X/n)}$$
Applying the [multivariate Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method) to the function $g(x,y) = \frac{x(1-y)}{y(1-x)}$, we have:

$$\sqrt{n}\left(\underbrace{g(X/n,Y/n)}_{=T_n} -\frac{\pi_1(1-\pi_2)}{\pi_2(1-\pi_1)}  \right)\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N} \left(0 ,\Gamma'\cdot\Sigma\cdot\Gamma  \right)$$
where
$$\Gamma =\nabla g(\pi_1,\pi_2) =\pmatrix{\frac{1-\pi_2}{\pi_2 (1-\pi_1)^2} \\ -\frac{\pi_1}{(1-\pi_1)\pi_2^2}  }$$

We can conclude that

$$\color{red}{T_n \xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N} \left( \frac{\pi_1(1-\pi_2)}{\pi_2(1-\pi_1)}  , \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{\pi_1 (1 -\pi_2) ((1 - \pi_1) \pi_1 + (1 - \pi_2) \pi_2)}{(1 - \pi_1)^3 \pi_2^3}  \right)}$$

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me another question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852974/find-the-asymptotic-distribution-of-t-n-fracx-1n-x-2nx-3nx-4n-u