# Find the asymptotic distribution of $T_n = \frac{X_{1n} X_{2n}}{X_{3n}X_{4n}}$ under multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(X_{1n}, X_{2n},X_{3n},X_{4n}) \sim \operatorname{Multnomial}(n; \pi_1,  \pi_2, \pi_3, \pi_4)$. Find the asymptotic distribution of $T_n = \frac{X_{1n} X_{2n}}{X_{3n}X_{4n}}$ as $n \to \infty$.

I don't know how to do the above question. I guess I need to use delta method. How to solve the above?

Comment: Do you know any theorems that allow you to conclude that $\tfrac{1}{n}X_{kn} \to \pi_k$ almost surely for each $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define the function $g(x,y,z,t) = (xy)/(zt)$ then
$$ g\left(\frac{X_{1n}}{n},\frac{X_{2n}}{n},\frac{X_{3n}}{n},\frac{X_{4n}}{n}\right) = T_n = \frac{\frac{X_{1n}}{n}\cdot \frac{X_{2n}}{n}}{\frac{X_{3n}}{n} \cdot \frac{X_{4n}}{n}}$$

According to the [defintion 5.8.3 of the multnomial distribution](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse312/22wi/files/student_drive/5.8.pdf) and the central limit theorem, we have

$$\sqrt{n}\left(\pmatrix{X_{1n}/n \\X_{2n}/n \\X_{3n}/n \\X_{4n}/n } -\pmatrix{\pi_1 \\\pi_2\\\pi_3\\\pi_4}  \right)\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N}_4 \left(\pmatrix{0 \\0\\0\\0} ,\Sigma \right)$$
where $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ such that
$$\Sigma_{i,j} = \cases{\pi_i (1-\pi_i)&if $i=j$\\
                        \pi_i\pi_j &if $i\ne j$ }$$
By the same technique [multivariate Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method) used in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852992/195378), we  have:

$$\sqrt{n}\left(g\left(\frac{X_{1n}}{n},\frac{X_{2n}}{n},\frac{X_{3n}}{n},\frac{X_{4n}}{n}\right) -\frac{\pi_1\pi_2}{\pi_3\pi_4}  \right)\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N} \left(0 ,\Gamma'\cdot\Sigma\cdot\Gamma  \right)$$
where $\Gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{4}$ is the gradient of $g$ at the point $(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3,\pi_4)$ (I let you compute $\Gamma$):
$$\Gamma =\nabla g(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3,\pi_4)$$

We can conclude that

$$\color{red}{T_n \xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N} \left( \frac{\pi_1\pi_2}{\pi_3\pi_4}  , \frac{1}{n}\cdot \Gamma'\cdot\Sigma\cdot\Gamma  \right)}$$

Comment: This seems like it proves too much. Suppose we want to apply the same technique to $\frac{X}{n-X}$ where $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$. Then would you claim that this is asymptotically normally distributed around $\frac{p}{1-p}$? But in fact, $\Pr[\frac{X}{n-X} \le a] = \Pr[X \le \frac{a}{1+a}n]$, which tends to $1$ if $\frac{a}{1+a} > p$ and $0$ if $\frac{a}{1+a} < p$; the asymptotic distribution is a point distribution. What distinguishes the problem here from this simpler example?

Comment: @MishaLavrov  Exactly, that's what I meant, the estimator you suggested is asymptotically normally distributed for $n \to +\infty$ ($n$ large, but **not** $n = +\infty$!). And this normal distribution have a variance with a multiplicator factor of  $1/n$, so, it will converge almost surely to $p/(1-p)$  (that is the point distribution you mentionned) which occurs only when $n = +\infty$!
Besides, your example is not too diffrent from $\frac{X}{n}$ where $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$, do you agree with me that, asymptotically, this $\frac{X}{n}$  follows a normal distribution(and not a point)?

Comment: No, $\frac{X}{n}$ does *not* asymptotically follow a normal distribution, except in the trivial sense! The variance of $\frac{X}{n}$ tends to $0$. We can say that $\frac{X - np}{\sqrt n}$ asymptotically follows a normal distribution.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I think the discussion here is just because of my notation (which seems to be too abused :) )? Perhaps you prefer a more traditional notation such as this one ?
$$\sqrt{n}\left(T_n - \frac{\pi_1\pi_2}{\pi_3\pi_4} \right) \xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N} \left( 0 ,  \Gamma'\cdot\Sigma\cdot\Gamma  \right)$$

Comment: I would agree with that - but then it seems that you're claiming that as $n \to \infty$, the distribution of $T_n$ *itself* is a point mass at $\frac{\pi_1 \pi_2}{\pi_3 \pi_4}$. The distribution of $\sqrt{n}\left(T_n - \frac{\pi_1\pi_2}{\pi_3\pi_4} \right) $ is a more precise estimate of the behavior of $T_n$ for large $n$, which is valuable, as long as there is no confusion. (I was initially confused because I did not spot the $\frac1n$ in the variance of your answer, which I think you'll agree is a bit of an abuse-of-notation flag :))

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, that's what I meant (and so did you in your first comment, didn't you?), according to the  law of large numbers (for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205294/130516)), $T_n$ converges  to a point mass(at least in probability, I believe even it converges almost surely).
PS: Finally, it seems there is no confusion (as you spotted now the factor $1/n$). For information, I prefere the notation that I used in the answer, but I still agree with you that it's a bit abuse of notation) :)